# Restrcting Redirects and Suppressing Ads in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin

I've done some searching and have yet to find a way to somehow suppress redirects and ads from web pages that are loaded in a UIWebView. Whats happening is I would go to a page and the site would have an ad that redirects me to the App Store. This is really annoying, so I'm looking for some guidance as to how one would go about suppressing this.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` you can filter which links are followed.

You can also differentiate between how the link was followed (say, a user click), by checking the `navigationType`.

e.g. don't follow links to a given site

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"blacklisted.host.com"]) {
        return NO;
    }   
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! I'll up-vote this as soon as I get enough rep. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just did!